# How to Use One EF DataContract and 2 WCF Services in the Same Application

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-6

I'm having a horrible time trying to get this to work.  I have a multiple - identical - WCF services using EF installed on different servers.  Each of them access a different database on different instances of SQL Server.

I'm trying to create a method that will will allow me to connect to Instance1.MyDatabase and Instance2.MyDatabase at the same time.

I can only create 1 endpoint address in the app.config because there is only 1 contract for the EF data.  Here is the endpoint in the app.config

```
      <endpoint address="http://Server01/DataService/Data.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="Query.IPSIData"
      bindingConfiguration="WCFHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WCFHttpBehavior" />
```

When creating a data context object for the Entity Framework object, I have tried using two different URIs.

```
Context1 = new DevEntities(service1URI)
Context2 = new DevEntities(service2URI)
```

What happens is that Context1 returns data and Context2, while creating and querying without error, is not returning any records.  I have tried entering a new endpoint in the config, but it will not compile because both endpoints use the same contract.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel stupid for even posting this question.  It helps if you get the terminology right before posting.  It also helps if you reference the correct services in your config files.

I have a lot of info in the config.  No excuse, but I'll use it anyway.

So, to access two different services using the same Entity Framework WCF service definition, it's really just a matter of creating endpoints to the correct service!  Mine had typos, which is why it didn't work.

First, you need to reference the URIs in appSettings:

```
    <add key="ProductionDataUri" value="http://ProdServer/ProdService.svc"/>
<add key="QADataUri" value="http://QAServer/QAService.svc"/>
```

Second, you need a webHttpBinding for the endpoints:

```
      <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WCFWebBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Third, you need two endpoints to match the URIs:

```
<endpoint address="http://QAServer/QAService.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WCFWebBinding"
            name="WCFQAWebBinding" contract="*"/>
  <endpoint address="http://ProdServer/ProdService.svc"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WCFWebBinding"
      name="WCFProductionWebBinding" contract="*"/>
```

Done.